# router routes not getting triggered by links

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone router with two routes registered like this

```
 routes:{
        "":"list",
        "restaurants/:id":"restoDetails"
    },
```

At the root of the application, when I'm listing the restaurants, I create links for each member of the list

```
<script id="restaurantListView" type="text/underscore">

<a href="#restaurants/{{= id }}" class="thumbnail plain">

    <h5>{{= name }}</h5>

</a>
</script>
```

When I click on the link, it creates a link like this in the url bar

```
http://localhost:3000/#restaurants/4
```

However, there is no indication of the `restoDetails` function getting called, contrary to what you'd expect from the route registered in the router. For example, this is not logging:

```
restoDetails:function (id) {
        console.log('resto');

    }
```

However, if I refresh the page with the url like this `http://localhost:3000/#restaurants/4`, it changes to the same thing but without the hash

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurants/4
```

and only then does the `restoDetails` function completes its log.

Note, in the init function of the app, I also do this

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Can you explain what's happening with the `#` such that the restoDetails function is not getting called when I click the link?

I should also note that if I remove the `#` from the link like this

```
 <a href="restaurants/{{= id }}"
```

then this problem doesn't exist. however, the [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) I got the code from uses the `#` so I assumed it was necessary.

Further to the comment by @muistooshort, which addresses the problem I've described above

If I'm not using pushstate like this

```
       if (window.history ) {
    Backbone.history.start();
}
```

Then I'm starting my links with the `#`

```
<a href="#restaurants/{{= id }}"
```

and when I click on that link, then the method in the router is getting trigger

```
routes:{
        "":"list",
        "restaurants/:id":"restoDetails"
    },
```

and the alert is getting called

```
restoDetails:function (id) {
         alert('in resto');
```

However, if I do use pushstate

```
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
}
```

and I set up the link without the `#`

```
 <a href="restaurants/{{= id }}"
```

then if I click that link the alert in the function that should be triggered via the route is not getting called. ie this alert is not happening now.

```
restoDetails:function (id) {
             alert('in resto');
```

why isn't this alert getting triggered if I click on the link when pushstate is enabled?

I should also note that, when the function isn't getting triggered by the router if I'm using pushstate, it's falling back to the default Rails show action, so the result of render json: @restaurants, root: false is appearing on the page /restaurants/1

Comment: Are you intending to use the History API? http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: What are you doing that's different from http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CEpPA/ ?

Comment: @muistooshort that works for me. It's this one that doesn't (and it doesn't work in the fiddle either): i.e. it's not logging when I click the link with pushstate enabled and WITHOUT using the # in the link http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/CEpPA/1/

Comment: @muistooshort according to your comment below Wil's answer, I thought it should also work the way I set it up in my fiddle

Comment: PushState is a bit screwy on jsfiddle.net, it should work in real life though.

Comment: if I use pushstate without # to set up the links, it just defaults to Rails action (i.e. a page full of json data because I render json) rather than hitting the Backbone action triggered by the router

Comment: @Leahcim Were you able to figure out what was going wrong? I am facing the same issue where the anchor links are not redirecting while the address bar is updated with the new url. Also, when I trigger the url from the address bar, it redirects correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pushState` option you're passing to the `Backbone` router activates the use of the HTML5 History API.

This is a really useful feature available to modern browsers that allows Javascript applications to control the URL state. This is nice if you're designing your app for "progressive enhancement" or "graceful degradation". In other words, if the user doesn't have Javascript available, the server can use the same URL to render the page. I've found this crucial for apps that need to be accessible to search engines. You can have the best off both worlds: Great user experience and SEO.

If you would prefer to just use `#`, remove the `pushState` option:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you're telling me. Why isn't the console log running if I go to #restaurants/4

Comment: Try making the links to match: `http://localhost:3000/#/restaurants/4` Does that make any difference? Maybe it's not parsed correctly.

Comment: Huh, the beginning slash is optional, so I'm not sure why you're having the problem. Hope my answer was slightly helpful, though.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question. the problem is, as the OP says (maybe not clearly enough) that when I click the links in the list on the homepage and which also puts an id in the url, the corresponding method is not getting called on the router as one would expect if you have router code like this `"restaurants/:id":"restoDetails"`

Comment: @Leahcim: If you're using pushState then you want hash-less URLs like `href="/restaurants/4"`, if you're not using pushState then you want URLs like `href="#restaurants/4"`. I think Will M is trying to tell you not to mix the two styles.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, if you'd kindly see the update in the OP, if I don't mix the styles, I still can't trigger that function while using pushstate without the hash (although I can if I don't use pushstate and do use the hash). Can you tell me why? This is essentially the same question as the OP just slightly clarified thanks to your comment.

Comment: @muistooshort, I should note that, when the function isn't getting triggered by the router if I'm using pushstate, it's falling back to the default Rails `show` action, so the result of `render json: @restaurants, root: false` is appearing on the page /restaurants/1